# Workflow to transfer custom list item to another sharepoint custom list

Tags: 2010, workflow, sharepoint-designer

I am stuck using workflows, so no C# is allowed - I'm trying to copy only certain items, on which the workflow will be triggered, to another custom list within the same domain

Setup is as follow:
Test list in Sharepoint site: http://mydomain.com/sites/Site1/
Final list in Sharepoint site: http://mydomain.com/sites/Site2/

The workflow can do the mapping of the different items, so that say column1, column2 and column3 of Test list end up in column2, column5 and column8 of Final list.

The question is how can I read the data from the external list within the workflow? I though that external content types would allow me to load an external library into a local library that would auto-update itself, but it seems to be disabled.
Should it be turned on, to allow this type of behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this was somewhat answered on one of the StackOverflow questions:

[Automatically copy data from SP2010 external list to an SP2010 custom list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736835/automatically-copy-data-from-sp2010-external-list-to-an-sp2010-custom-list)

Comment: Also as a follow up - BCS is absolutely needed. Then you can create it seems an entity content type, based on the WebServices and setup a read-only list that will have the data of the other site. As seen here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee556431.aspx

Answer (score 0):

"The question is how can I read the data from the external list within the workflow?"
Not sure if SPD out of the box can do thus but try looking at SPD activites in codeplex maybe you can find something.
I'm sure you can use web serivces for this but you mentioned no c# .
So try Powershelll.
Cheers

Comment: The issue is that I'm only an admin on the sites and not on the overall site collection - Thus I can't install any extensions and cannot user powershell. Thanks for chiming in. Seems Like I'm stuck for now :\